# Cannot Find Symbol/Variable error

Tags: java, aes

I am attempting to make a chat program (Based on [this](http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javanetexamples/)) that uses AES encryption to send the data but I have run into some issues. I have encrypted the messages fine (I think...[This is only my second program so I am really new to Java]) but when I try to decrypt the message, the program cannot find the symbol "cipher" which was previously created. Heres where the error is:

```
public void run() throws IOException {

// Make connection and initialize streams
String serverAddress = getServerAddress();
Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddress, 9001);
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    socket.getInputStream()));
out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
// Process all messages from server, according to the protocol.
while (true) {
    String line = in.readLine();
 if (line.startsWith("SUBMITNAME")) {
        out.println(getName());
    } else if (line.startsWith("NAMEACCEPTED")) {
        textField.setEditable(true);
    } else if (line.startsWith("MESSAGE")) {
               //DECRYPTION
                messageArea.append(line.substring(8) + "\n");
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
                line = new String(cipher.doFinal(line));
                System.out.println(line);
    }
}
}
```

Heres where cipher is created:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try {
        String input = (textField.getText());
        //ENCRYPTION
        MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md5.update("So What's Up Doc?".getBytes());

        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(md5.digest(), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

        byte encryptedMessage[] = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes());
        //Sends the encrypted version of message
        System.out.println(encryptedMessage);
        out.println(encryptedMessage);
        //Clears the input box
        textField.setText("");
    } catch (    NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ChatClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    }
```

The full code is here:

```
package Chat.Application;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.omg.PortableInterceptor.SYSTEM_EXCEPTION;
/**
 * A simple Swing-based client for the chat server.  Graphically
 * it is a frame with a text field for entering messages and a
 * textarea to see the whole dialog.
 *
 * The client follows the Chat Protocol which is as follows.
 * When the server sends "SUBMITNAME" the client replies with the
 * desired screen name.  The server will keep sending "SUBMITNAME"
 * requests as long as the client submits screen names that are
 * already in use.  When the server sends a line beginning
 * with "NAMEACCEPTED" the client is now allowed to start
 * sending the server arbitrary strings to be broadcast to all
 * chatters connected to the server.  When the server sends a
 * line beginning with "MESSAGE " then all characters following
 * this string should be displayed in its message area.
 */
public class ChatClient {

    BufferedReader in;
    PrintWriter out;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("ELECTRON Chatroom");
    JTextField textField = new JTextField(40);
    JTextArea messageArea = new JTextArea(8, 40);

    /**
     * Constructs the client by laying out the GUI and registering a
     * listener with the textfield so that pressing Return in the
     * listener sends the textfield contents to the server.  Note
     * however that the textfield is initially NOT editable, and
     * only becomes editable AFTER the client receives the NAMEACCEPTED
     * message from the server.
     */
    public ChatClient() {

        // Layout GUI
        textField.setEditable(false);
        messageArea.setEditable(false);
        messageArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        messageArea.setLineWrap(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField, "North");
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(messageArea), "Center");
        frame.pack();
        // Add Listeners
        textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            /**
             * Responds to pressing the enter key in the textfield by sending
             * the contents of the text field to the server.    Then clear
             * the text area in preparation for the next message.
             */
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                String input = (textField.getText());
                //ENCRYPTION
                MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                md5.update("So What's Up Doc?".getBytes());

                SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(md5.digest(), "AES");

                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

                byte encryptedMessage[] = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes());
                //Sends the encrypted version of message
                System.out.println(encryptedMessage);
                out.println(encryptedMessage);
                //Clears the input box
                textField.setText("");
            } catch (    NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ChatClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Prompt for and return the address of the server.
     */
    private String getServerAddress() {
        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            frame,
            "Enter IP Address of the Server:",
            "ELECTRON Chatroom",
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    }

    /**
     * Prompt for and return the desired screen name.
     */
    private String getName() {
        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            frame,
            "Choose a screen name:",
            "Screen name selection",
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }

    /**
     * Connects to the server then enters the processing loop.
     */
    public void run() throws IOException {

        // Make connection and initialize streams
        String serverAddress = getServerAddress();
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddress, 9001);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        // Process all messages from server, according to the protocol.
        while (true) {
            String line = in.readLine();
         if (line.startsWith("SUBMITNAME")) {
                out.println(getName());
            } else if (line.startsWith("NAMEACCEPTED")) {
                textField.setEditable(true);
            } else if (line.startsWith("MESSAGE")) {
                       //DECRYPTION
                        messageArea.append(line.substring(8) + "\n");
                        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
                        line = new String(cipher.doFinal(line));
                        System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Runs the client as an application with a closeable frame.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ChatClient client = new ChatClient();
        client.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        client.frame.setVisible(true);
        client.run();
    }
}
```

The AES encryption's code is from [here](http://www.techsach.com/2012/05/encrypt-decrypt-data-using-aes-in-java.html)

I am sure it is an easy solution an doubt the AES encryption part has anything to do with it but might as well add it. Thanks for all your help!
-Silver

EDIT - ERROR:

```
no suitable method found for doFinal(String)
    method Cipher.doFinal(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Cipher.doFinal(byte[],int,int,byte[],int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Cipher.doFinal(byte[],int,int,byte[]) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Cipher.doFinal(byte[],int,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Cipher.doFinal(byte[]) is not applicable
      (actual argument String cannot be converted to byte[] by method invocation conversion)
    method Cipher.doFinal(byte[],int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Cipher.doFinal() is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `cicher` a global variable. Declare it at the top level of your class:

```
Cipher cipher;
```

Change:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
```

to:

```
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
```

Add a check for `null` here:

```
if (cipher != null) {
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    line = new String(cipher.doFinal(line));
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Basically, the variable `cipher` isn't known where you are trying to use it. Declaring it at the top-level will make it visible throughout the class. The `null` check isn't required if `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` and `run()` are called in this  <--  order.

Comment: Everything got better except for the line which includes "line = new String(cipher.doFinal(line));" where there is quite a big error. I have listed the error in my question

Comment: @Silver You see that error beacuse: `Cipher.doFinal()` is an overloaded method and none of the method signatures match - `Cipher.doFinal(String)` which is what you are trying to do. Take a look at the Cipher API and verify that `Cipher.doFinal(String)` does not exist. I would suggest you leave `AES` for now.

Comment: Hm ok thanks anyway! And I am gonna research if there is any other way to achieve encryption

Comment: @Silver Sure. By the way,  `Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");` should go in your `main()` method before calling `client.run()`. And, `line = new String(cipher.doFinal(line));` should be `line = new String(cipher.doFinal(line.getBytes()));`. If you need more help, post a new question and someone will be able to guide you through this. Happy coding!